# c++ how to store a variable and string that is 2^1 000 000 large?

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve an exercise. It says that i need to output 3 last digits of a number that is 2 raised to the power of `n` (2^n).

But input is `n=1000000`.

The code works with lower values, but when the input is 1 000 000 the number gets too large.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned long long n;
    cin >> n;
    unsigned long long sk = pow(2, n);

    if (sk < 1000) cout << sk;

    else {
        string ats = to_string(sk);  // converting the number to string
                                     // so I could output 3 last digits
                                     // probably not the best solution
                                     // for this exercise
        n = ats.length();
        for (unsigned long long i = n - 3; i < n; i++) {
            cout << ats[i];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: google for `big numbers c++`

Comment: When you multiple 2 number together what part of those numbers determine what that last 3 places are?

Comment: You can do this with modular arithmetic no need for big number library.

Comment: Modular mathematic will helps you. After all when you multiply a number by 2, last three digits doesn't depends on higher digits, aren't they? 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 024, 048, 096, 192, 384, 768, etc

Comment: The whole point of the exercise is to find a way to compute the last `3` digits of the number **without** actually computing the number.

Comment: voting to close as the whole exercise is about realizing that you dont need to know the full number to get the desired result. Any answer will have to spoil the exercise

Comment: Do a reasonability check on your numbers. 2^1000000 is approximately 10^300000 times larger than the estimated number of particles in the visible universe. You won't fit that into a computer, so you're going to have to solve the problem without computing the actual number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like:

- Initialize result to 1
- Within a loop from 1 to n:

  - result *= 2
  - result %= 1000

This because the result of the last 3 digits does not depend upon the greater digits

Comment: yes that is a correct solution to this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate your number modulo 1000. Just saving the three least significant digits and trashing the more significant ones does not alter the result.
Just do:

```
int result = 1;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    result = (result * 2) % 1000;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution.